# How to refactor code for switch statement in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to refactor code for switch statement in React.

I have the data as array of objects. I loop through each object and check its type field. For each type type field I have some message to print and each object data should be in a list item. To do so, I use switch statement and doing so I feel that the code is repeated too much.

How can I rewrite the code below?

```
render = () => {

    switch(item.type) {
        case 'item_created':
            return (
                <li className="item">
                    <div className="details">
                        <Svg4/>
                        <span>{item.type}</span>
                    </div>
                    <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
                </li>
            );
        case 'item_deleted':
            return (
                <li className="item">
                    <div className="details">
                        <Svg1/>
                        <span>{item.name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
                </li>
            );
        case 'settings_updated':
            return (
                <li className="item">
                    <div className="details">
                        <Svg2/>
                        <span>{item.version}</span>
                    </div>
                    <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
                </li>
            );
        default:
            return null;
    }}
```

Could someone help me refactoring this, or provide a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring is always kind of subjective, but what about creating a new component that you can reuse multiple times in your switch statement.

```
const Item = ({icon, text, timestamp}) => (
  <li className="item">
    <div className="details">
      {icon}
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
    <time>{timestamp}</time>
  </li>
)
```

Comment: thanks how can i use this Item within the switch case as well. sorry new to react.

Comment: You can still use your Switch statement as your were using it previously. Juste replace each return by `return <Item icon={<Svg4 />} text={item.type} timestamp={item.timestamp} />` for the first one for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use object mapping like below.

```
   const mapping = {
  item_created: item => (
    <li className="item">
      <div className="details">
        <Svg4 />
        <span>{item.type}</span>
      </div>
      <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
    </li>
  ),
  item_deleted: item => (
    <li className="item">
      <div className="details">
        <Svg1 />
        <span>{item.name}</span>
      </div>
      <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
    </li>
  ),
  settings_updated: item => (
    <li className="item">
      <div className="details">
        <Svg2 />
        <span>{item.version}</span>
      </div>
      <time>{item.timestamp}</time>
    </li>
  ),
};
```

Now you can use above object as following

```
mapping[item.type](item)
```